# Is this reasoning correct? Equivalent linear PDE system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, linear-pde

My system of PDEs is for $\vec{V}$ and $R$ constants:
$$\mathrm{div}\vec{v}=0 \tag1$$
$$(\vec{V}\cdot\vec{\mathrm{grad}})\vec{v}-\frac{1}{R}\triangle \vec{v}=-\vec{\mathrm{grad}}p\tag2$$
with the following BCs
$$\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\vec{v}=\vec{0} \qquad  \lim_{|x|\to\infty}\vec{\mathrm{grad}}\vec{v}=\widetilde{0} \qquad \lim_{|x|\to\infty}p=0$$

$\textbf{PROBLEM:}$

I would like to find out if I can replace equation $(1)$ by:
$$\triangle p=0\tag3$$
Which is obtained taking the divergence of $(2)$, taking $(1)$ into account. With an aditional BC ($p$ must have a jump over some surface, but its derivative must be continuous).

$\textbf{WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR:}$

I know:

1) Thanks to $(3)$ and its additional BC I know that $\vec{\mathrm{grad}}p$ is continuous except possibly the tangential component of the gradient through the boundary (surface).

2) Thanks to $(2)$  that the velocity and its derivatives are continuous (because of the Laplacian).

3) Due to points 1) and 2) from $(2)$  that also the second derivatives of $\vec{v}$ are also continuous (because they are equal to functions that are also continuous).

Therefore, given equation $(3)$ and $(2)$, taking the divergence of $(2)$ we have an additional equation for $\phi=\mathrm{div}\vec{v}$

$$\mathrm{div}\left(\vec{V}\phi -\frac{1}{R}\vec{\mathrm{grad}}\phi\right)=0\tag4$$

Integrating equation $(4)$ once we obtain that what is within brackets must be equal to a divergence-free vector field $A$ that is finite everywhere and vanishes when $|x|\to\infty$ [applying 1), 2) and 3)]:
$$\vec{V}\phi -\frac{1}{R}\vec{\mathrm{grad}}\phi=\vec{A}$$

According to Helmholtz $\vec{A}$ must be a curl of some vector potential $\vec{A}=\vec{\mathrm{curl}\vec{\Psi}}$, where

$$\vec{\Psi} = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{V}{\frac{\vec{curl}'\vec{A}(\vec{x}')}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|}\,dV'}-\frac{1}{4\pi}\oint_{\partial V}{\vec{n}'\times\frac{\vec{A}(\vec{x}')}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|}\,d\sigma'} \tag{H} $$

Since the potential part of the decomposition (which is a solution of Laplace equation) must vanish at infinity and must be continuous everywhere this part must be $0$ everywhere.

Considering an unbounded domain, $\textit{i.e.}$ $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, for the second integral of $(H)$ to vanish the vector function $\vec{A}$ must, at least decay as $\vec{A}\propto |\vec{x}'|^{-p}$ with $p>1$.

As a result $\vec{curl}'\vec{A}\propto |\vec{x}'|^{-p-1}$ and the integrand of the first addend behaves as $|\vec{x}|^{-p-2}$. Since $p>1$ this integrand is singular for some point within $V$. Therefore $V$ can be split into $V=B(\epsilon,\vec{x}) \cup V\backslash B(\epsilon,\vec{x})$ with $\epsilon\to 0$.

but to fulfill the smoothness requirement of the derivatives of the velocity (variable $\phi$) this integral must be $0$ setting $\vec{curl}'\vec{A}=\vec{0}$. The integral within the ball $B$ if it is solvable ($2>p>1 $) would vanish and if it is not, the variable $\phi$ would not be defined and therefore $\vec{A}=\vec{0}$.

I have if $p>2$:
$$\vec{V}\phi -\frac{1}{R}\vec{\mathrm{grad}}\phi=0\tag5$$

The general solution of $(5)$ is:
$$\phi = c\exp{\left(R\vec{V}\cdot\vec{x}\right)}$$
We see that $c=0$ because we need a solution for $\vec{v}$ in which $\vec{v}$ itself and its derivatives vanish at infinity. And therefore we have:
$$\phi = 0$$

$ \textbf{I can not prove the case for which $2>p>1$}$.

$\textbf{Thank you}$ for your time and interest.

Comment: I believe your boundary condition on $p$ forces $p=0$ because $p$ satisfies (3).

Comment: @user254433 Thank you for your answer but p is not 0 because it must present a jump over some surface as I explain in what follows $(3)$

Comment: Yes, I see now.

Comment: Can you explain why $\vec A=0$?

Comment: I have tried to explain it today. Is it explained enough? Or should I develop it more? Thank you @user254433

Comment: I'm not sure that $p>1$ implies the integrand is too singular, since $p$ only governs the decay rate at infinity, rather than singularities near the origin.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but if it is not too singular, this integral (split in two regions: a sphere enclosing the singularity and the outside) in the limit gives a constant plus an integral in the outside. This constant must be $0$ and therefore it must not have any solvable or unsolvable singularity I think,

Comment: Could you possibly clarify: in which limit, why must this constant be zero, and what solvable/unsolvable indicates?  (Or perhaps you could, at the end of your OP, add some more details about why $A=0$.) Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my post. The limit to which I refer is the ball of radius $\epsilon\to 0$ in which the integral, if solvable gives a finite value. Since $\vec{A}$ vanishes at infinity this constant must be $0$.

Comment: Consider the integral over $B(\epsilon,x)$.  If $A$ is smooth on $\mathbb R^3$, then it seems this integral vanishes as $\epsilon\to 0$, i.e. the finite value you mentioned is zero even if $\vec A\neq 0$.

Comment: This integral vanishes if $2>p>1$ as you say. It's true (For $p=1$ it gives a constant but this is not the case). But it does not when $p>2$ (this is the case that would permit me to ensure that $\vec{A}=\vec{0}$). Do you know something I could use?

Comment: I believe the integral over $B(\epsilon,x)$ also vanishes for every $p>2$.  Could you explain why it does not?

Comment: I was mistaken! The integral is approximately when $\epsilon \to 0$ equal to $4\pi\int_{0}^{\epsilon}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|^{-p-2}\,r^2\,dr}=4\pi\int_{0}^{\epsilon}{r^{-p}\,dr}$ which is only defined if $0<p<1$. Therefore in this case is always singular isn't it?

Comment: Your values of $p$ look ok, but I don't think $\nabla'\times A(x')\approx |x-x'|^{p-2}$ for small $\epsilon$.  In this limit, the integral tends towards $\nabla\times A(x)\int_0^\epsilon |x-x'|^{-1}dV'$, since $A(x)$ is smooth.  This integral is well defined, since it is $4\pi\int_0^\epsilon r^{-1} (r^2dr)$, and vanishes as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: Ahh It's true! Thank you! But... is there any way to prove what I want?

Comment: What is more for $p>2$ the integral around $\vec{x}'=0$ is $$4\pi\int_{0}^{\epsilon}{r^{-p-1}(r^2dr)}$$ which is singular for $p>2$ and $0$ for $2<p<1$. Another singularity arises at $x=0$ with this integral singular if $p>1$.

Comment: I'll think about it, and leave you with this: is point 2) in "What I've tried so far" correct?  If you integrate equation (2) in the normal direction of the "jump" and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, then you get $p_+ - p_- = 0$, since $v$ and its derivatives are continuous.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that point $(2)$ is correct. The solution of $(3)$ is proportional to the solid angle (with different sign in each side) if the pressure drop is constant over the disk (e.g unity), in 1D the  pressure is $$ p(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} &if\quad x<0\\
-1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} &if\quad x>0
\end{array}\right.\tag{*}$$ and its gradient is $$\frac{dp}{dx}=\left(1-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)/\sqrt{1+x^2}\tag{**}$$ which is continuous. Therefore if laplacian is neglected (for the sake of simplicity)the integral of $(*)$ which leads to $v(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much for yout effort and interest.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but in 1D, if the Laplacian is neglected, then we have $V\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{dp}{dx}$. Integrating from $-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$, we get $V v|_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon=-p|_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon$.  The left hand side vanishes as $\epsilon\to 0$ because $v$ is continuous, while the right hand side is equal to 2 via (*).

Comment: I am not a matematician... but I know what it must result although I can not explain it properly. Maybe the fundamental theorem of calculus does not work here, because the value of $p(0)$ does not exist. I mean to compute the integral safely, try to solve the following limit: 
$$\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}{\frac{dp}{dx}\,dx} = \lim_{\delta\to 0}\left[\int_{-\epsilon}^{-\delta}{\frac{dp}{dx}\,dx}+\int_{\delta}^{\epsilon}{\frac{dp}{dx}\,dx}\right]$$